# Use Media player inside a custom adapter recycleview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, media-player

[I use this library](https://github.com/Krupen/AutoplayVideos), for displaying video in auto play inside a recycleview but I need to get the medi player for implemented buffering and some others things. I use this method for `holder.getAah_vi().getCustomVideoView().getMediaPlayer()` but I cant cause my app crash cause of media player is not initialize  but I dont know how can I initialize it in Custom adapter.

My Error

```
  Process: com.allattentionhere.autoplayvideossample, PID: 6966
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
    at com.allattentionhere.autoplayvideossample.Adapter.MyVideosAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MyVideosAdapter.java:106)
    at com.allattentionhere.autoplayvideossample.Adapter.MyVideosAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MyVideosAdapter.java:26)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6356)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6389)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5335)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5598)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5440)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5436)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2224)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1551)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3583)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3025)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22360)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6758)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1644)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:819)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:687)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22360)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6758)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:191)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22360)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6758)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:393)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22360)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6758)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:191)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22360)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6758)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1644)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:819)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:687)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22360)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6758)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:191)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:743)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22360)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2777)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1717)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1990)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1602)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7407)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:948)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:750)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:682)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:934)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:869)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:206)
06-10 13:16:40.838 6966-6966/com.allattentionhere.autoplayvideossample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6733)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:845)
```

My Code

public class MyVideosAdapter extends AAH_VideosAdapter {

```
private final List<MyModel> list;
private final Picasso picasso;
private static final int TYPE_VIDEO = 0, TYPE_TEXT = 1;

public class MyViewHolder extends AAH_CustomViewHolder {
    final TextView tv;
    final ImageView img_vol, img_playback;
    //to mute/un-mute video (optional)
    boolean isMuted;

    public MyViewHolder(View x) {
        super(x);
        tv = ButterKnife.findById(x, R.id.tv);
        img_vol = ButterKnife.findById(x, R.id.img_vol);
        img_playback = ButterKnife.findById(x, R.id.img_playback);
    }

    //override this method to get callback when video starts to play
    @Override
    public void videoStarted() {
        super.videoStarted();
        img_playback.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
        if (isMuted) {
            muteVideo();
            img_vol.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_mute);
        } else {
            unmuteVideo();
            img_vol.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_unmute);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void pauseVideo() {
        super.pauseVideo();
        img_playback.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
    }
}


public class MyTextViewHolder extends AAH_CustomViewHolder {
    final TextView tv;

    public MyTextViewHolder(View x) {
        super(x);
        tv = ButterKnife.findById(x, R.id.tv);
    }
}

public MyVideosAdapter(List<MyModel> list_urls, Picasso p) {
    this.list = list_urls;
    this.picasso = p;
}

@Override
public AAH_CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType==TYPE_TEXT) {
        View itemView1 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.single_text, parent, false);
        return new MyTextViewHolder(itemView1);
    } else {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.single_card, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final AAH_CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (list.get(position).getName().startsWith("text")) {
        ((MyTextViewHolder) holder).tv.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    } else {
        ((MyViewHolder) holder).tv.setText(list.get(position).getName());

        //todo
        holder.setImageUrl(list.get(position).getImage_url());
        holder.setVideoUrl(list.get(position).getVideo_url());

        holder.getAah_vi().getCustomVideoView().getMediaPlayer().start();


        //load image into imageview
        if (list.get(position).getImage_url() != null && !list.get(position).getImage_url().isEmpty()) {
            picasso.load(holder.getImageUrl()).config(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).into(holder.getAAH_ImageView());
        }

        holder.setLooping(true); //optional - true by default

        //to play pause videos manually (optional)
        ((MyViewHolder) holder).img_playback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (holder.isPlaying()) {
                    holder.pauseVideo();
                    holder.setPaused(true);
                } else {
                    holder.playVideo();
                    holder.setPaused(false);
                }
            }
        });

        //to mute/un-mute video (optional)
        ((MyViewHolder) holder).img_vol.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (((MyViewHolder) holder).isMuted) {
                    holder.unmuteVideo();
                    ((MyViewHolder) holder).img_vol.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_unmute);
                } else {
                    holder.muteVideo();
                    ((MyViewHolder) holder).img_vol.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_mute);
                }
                ((MyViewHolder) holder).isMuted = !((MyViewHolder) holder).isMuted;
            }
        });

        if (list.get(position).getVideo_url() == null) {
            ((MyViewHolder) holder).img_vol.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ((MyViewHolder) holder).img_playback.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            ((MyViewHolder) holder).img_vol.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((MyViewHolder) holder).img_playback.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (list.get(position).getName().startsWith("text")) {
        return TYPE_TEXT;
    } else return TYPE_VIDEO;
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide your code of implementation.

Comment: @David could you just say me how can I use media player in adapter?

Comment: Sorry, currently I can't as the whole implementation is not clear. The functions `getCustomVideoView` and `getMediaPlayer` I don't see on the description of the project, so I don't know what they do. Try to explain better especially by providing more code.

Comment: @David I uptade my question can you see it ? please

Comment: assumed you've also `AAH_CustomRecyclerView` and `MainActivity.xml`, you need to call `recyclerView.setActivity(this);` before `recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);`

Comment: @David already done in my main Activity Sir

Comment: @David Sorry I dont understand why holder.getAah_vi().getCustomVideoView().getMediaPlayer()doesnt work

Comment: how you invoke everything? that's still missing

Comment: @David Sir everything work corretly but I just cant acces to the media player of the library

Comment: your desired object is not created, therefore you get the error-message. That means something is not working right before.

Comment: I understand Sir how can I start the  holder.getAah_vi().getCustomVideoView().getMediaPlayer() , How can I start it ?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if something with the code is wrong or just the video is not found

Comment: @David what do you need  to find out ?